# How to compile YARP with Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal, cmake, yarp

I've installed YARP from the source on my Macbook running El Capitan, and successfully configured it using the terminal as described [here](http://www.yarp.it/install_yarp_mac.html). However, I cannot seem to compile it with Xcode. When I run `ccmake .. -G Xcode` the same configuration window as with the terminal alternative  pops up instead of creating a XCode project YARP.xcodeproj:

[image]

I didn't install Xcode from scratch because I've already had Xcode 7.3.1 available.

What could I be doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question seems more to do with Cmake than Xcode.

Comment: Thanks, that's right. I forgot to add the tag.

Comment: My guess: Just call cmake instead of ccmake. There is no error or similar. I vote to close this question, as it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Using cmake *does* produce the following error: `CMake Error: Error: generator : Xcode
Does not match the generator used previously: Unix Makefiles
Either remove the CMakeCache.txt file and CMakeFiles directory or choose a different binary directory.` I was just curious if this was the correct way to generate the project file. Please tell me how I can make my question more clear.

Comment: Error message is clear: you need to remove old build files (`CMakeCache.txt` and `CMakeFiles/`) before change generator.